# Number of file descriptors - pidstat

Tags: linux, rhel, process, file-descriptors

As mentioned [here](http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/man_pidstat.html):

On RHEL 7.x, below command:

```
pidstat -C syslog-ng -v
```

does not recognise -v option

Alternative:
There are two process 417880 & 417881 for `syslog-ng`:

```
# ls /proc/`pidof syslog-ng`/fd | wc -l
ls: cannot access 417880/fd: No such file or directory
50
```

What option is used to get number of threads & 
file descriptors used by a process(`syslog-ng`)?

Answer (score 0):

RHEL is *way* behind on `pidstat` version.  It doesn't have a `-v` argument.

```
$ pidstat -v
Usage: pidstat [ options ] [ <interval> [ <count> ] ]
Options are:
[ -d ] [ -h ] [ -I ] [ -l ] [ -r ] [ -s ] [ -t ] [ -U [ <username> ] ] [ -u ]
[ -V ] [ -w ] [ -C <command> ] [ -p { <pid> [,...] | SELF | ALL } ]
[ -T { TASK | CHILD | ALL } ]
$
```

`-v` didn't come along until version 10.2.0.  You'll find that running `pidstat -V` on your system shows it to be prior to that.

You could use this approach to determine number of file descriptors.

```
$ sudo ls /proc/`pidof syslog-ng`/fd | wc -l
10
$
```

And this for thread count.

```
$ ps -o nlwp= -p `pidof syslog-ng`
   3
$
```

Comment: Which opton should I use for `pidstat` to get number of threads & file descriptors for process name `syslog-ng`? Any alternative to `pidstat`?